# How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?

Tags: floats, positioning, algorithms

I just got a short algorithm on my page, and it keeps getting aligned at the center of the page. But I want to have it aligned at the top, what do I have to do?

Comment: Are you talking about an algorithm in a floating environment on a single page? However, it would be good if you show by a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) what you are doing.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A comment up front: I will assume that your document employs a single-column layout.

To display a short algorithm (an object that LaTeX labels a "float") on a page by itself and to align it along the top of the page (instead of getting it to be centered vertically), try adding the following instructions to your document's preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

Happy TeXing! Note that by inserting these instructions in the preamble, their scope is *global*, i.e., they cover the placement of floats on *all* floats-only pages.

---

**Addendum**: I've been asked to explain what exactly this code snippet does. The LaTeX "kernel" (see `latex.ltx`, ca. line 7260) sets up several parameters to help position a float (or floats) on a floats-only page. Among these, the parameters `\@fptop` and `@fpbot` -- short for "floating page top" and "floating page bottom", I suppose -- govern how much space is inserted above the top float and below the bottom float on a floats-only page, in a document with a single-column page layout. The *default* value for both parameters is `0\p@ \@plus 1fil`. (`\p@` is defined earlier in `latex.ltx` to be equal to `0pt`.) The component `1fil` is "infinitely stretchable glue" (in TeX jargon), i.e., it will expand to take up all available space within its scope (here, the vertical page dimension not already occupied by other material -- such as the float itself!). Thus, the float(s) will be centered vertically by default on the floats-only page, and (happily) no unnecessary warnings about under-full pages will be issued by LaTeX.

To force the first float on a floats-only page to be top-aligned, then, it should suffice to issue the command

```
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
```

The second instruction, `\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}`, is there mostly to "play it safe", just in case some package has been loaded that fiddles with the `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot` parameters in a way that would make LaTeX start issuing warnings about under-full pages on floats-only pages should you reset just the `\@fptop` parameter...

**Second addendum, June 2022**: For a two-column page layout and full-width floats (such as `table*` and `figure*`), the relevant parameters are called `\@dblfptop` and `\@dblfpbot`, respectively.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Mico Can I invoke this locally too, for example for 1 table?

Comment: @Mico Sorry cannot edit my post anymore: I wanted to say for 1 table or for parts of the document, eg the appendix.

Comment: @Mico I just tested it. Unfortunately it doesn't work in `scrreprt` :(

Comment: TomM: You're right! I will delete my previous, incorrect comment. (By the way, simple "localizing" the redefinitions of `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot` fails not only with `scrreprt` but also with the "standard" LaTeX document classes `article`, `report`, and `book`.) May I suggest you create a new posting in which you'd ask for a solution to the objective of localizing the scope of these parameters?

Comment: @Mico I found a different solution. I am using the `float` package now with the parameter `[H]` for floats, which puts them on top. Then any vertically distance can be adjusted manually. Did you find a better solution? Then I'd make a thread for sure.

Comment: How about if you want to have two floats vertically aligned to top? This solution only aligns the first float, the second is then placed in the centre of the remaining space.

Comment: @Reggian -- Welcome to TeX.SE! May I ask you to post a *new query* to express your question? That way, it will be seen by a lot more people. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this hack to specific figures only?

Comment: @Viesturs - The short answer is, “probably yes.” A definitive answer will depend strongly on the document class in use. May I ask you to post a new query?

Comment: Done - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485799/force-float-to-top-of-page-selectively

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first try to use the "H" option in the table formatting first.
This can work if your table is placed just in the place your actually want.

```
\usepackge{float}  %load this package first
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure_name}
    \caption{the figure name}
    \label{the label info}
\end{figure}
```

If this does not work, try more complicated methods :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -3):

After the graphics or listing, add this code:

```
\vfill
\rule[\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}
```