# Latex float so no stretching appears, but everything is placed on top

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

It has probably been already answered, but I cannot find it.

If I include images as floats, LaTeX places the last one on a single page in the middle. How do I make LaTeX to put in on the top of the single page?

A similar question: if I make a new section and a large table (3/4 of the page long), LaTeX stretches the spacing between the section header and table. How do I place the table right after the section header?

Comment: Does this answer your first question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page?rq=1

Comment: the first question should be answered by the link given above and for the second question it would be good if you show a MWE (and pose it as a separate question this is not really similar at all