# Spacing between LaTeX Tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I generated two separate tables in chapter of the appendix of all tables. Of course, LaTeX fit the two tables in the page in order to use the whole page. Instead, since they are the last two I'd like them to be at the top.

Shortly, I would like to remove the blank space between two different tables and fill the bottom of the page with blank space.

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page

Comment: I tried it, it does not work. And I'd like to do that only on one page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the relevant parameters for the last two floats only:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\faketable}[1]{\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}\hspace{4cm}}
  \caption{A caption}
  \end{table}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Tables}
Here we have all our tables

\faketable{5cm}
\faketable{4cm}
\faketable{6cm}
\faketable{3cm}
\faketable{2cm}
\faketable{6cm}
\faketable{6cm}
\faketable{4cm}

\clearpage
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus \fill}
\makeatother

\faketable{5cm}
\faketable{5cm}

\end{document}
```

Of course, leave this for the “last minute, won't touch the text any more” phase.