# Page break between images of a figure

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have several images in a figure which can not come on a single page. The images near the bottom are trying to insert inside the bottom instead of going to the new page. I am using a package `\raggedbottom` because earlier I was facing the problem of unusual space between equation.

Please suggest me, how can I move the images to the next page which are near the bottom.

[image]

The black line above is the bottom of first page.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[Original image]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/image1}}\\%%Org 
\subfloat[Layer-1, Subgraph-1]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_SG1}} 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_VI}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_Sal}}\\       
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_SG1}}%%Layer-2
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_SG2}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_VI}}      
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_Sal}}\\           
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_SG1}}%%Layer-3
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_SG2}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_SG5}}     
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_SG6}}\\   
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_VI}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L3_Sal}}\\       
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_SG1}}%%Layer-4
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_SG2}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_SG3}}     
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_SG8}} 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_VI}}  
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_Sal}}
\caption{images}
\label{image}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: a `figure` is a box and never breaks, you need to split it up into smaller chunks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But then the numbering of figures will get disturbed. Is there any way that I can start the numbering in sequence with the previous image and then I will write a final description.

Comment: Not necessarily disturbed. You have shown no code (always a bad idea:-) so we don't know how you have done the sub-figure labels (a)--(t) but there are always ways of having a continuation figure that re-starts the sub captions so  (say)  (a)-(n) in the first and (o)-(t) in the second, but the details depend on what you have already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I will update the code in a minute

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have updated the code for putting this figure. Please let me know how can I split it while keeping the continuation of numbering.

Comment: Package caption includes a `\ContinuedFloat` mechanism.

Comment: @Johannes_B: that gives me an error: \ContinuedFloat outside float.

Comment: Please be aware, that i have no idea where you placed it. I would guess outside a float. Simple fix, place in the float. I would need to open the doc. But then, a minimal working example, as already mentioned by @David is the quicker way to go.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ok, it has solved the problem. BUT, now the second part of image is in the middle of the page which should not happen. How can I bring it to the top so that it seem to be in continuation with the previous image.

Comment: I thought i had left a comment on this yesterday, but apparently ... Here it is: [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556)

Answer (score 4):

Your issue with placement here seem to resolve when using the following:

1. Don't use a float. Instead, use the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)'s `[H]` float specifier to set the float inside a `minipage`. This will give you preference over the (non-)float placement.
2. Break the float manually at the desired location.
3. Use `\ContinuedFloat` from the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to retain the existing `\caption` number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,float}
\usepackage{subfig,caption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=2in,height=2cm,keepaspectratio}%
  \subfloat[Original image]{\includegraphics{example-image}} \\
  \subfloat[Layer-1]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}} 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}  
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}} \\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%%Layer-2
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
  \caption{images}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \ContinuedFloat\centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=2in,height=2cm,keepaspectratio}%
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}%%Layer-3
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}%%Layer-4
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}\\
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%%Layer-5
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
  \caption{images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Placing the images using `[H]` removes the issue of the last page float being set vertically centred, since the float is set like regular text, which will end up at the top of the page.