# How to have a figure with multiple groups of image and each image with individual name?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have several images and I must put their names below them. Moreover, I need to give the name of the group of that images too (for example, "first layer", "second layer" ect as show below). I need to have something as shown in the figure below.

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** In my case, a group of images may contain more than one row. I mean, the "(a) first layer" may contain more than 3 images and hence can be a group of images in more than one row.

Comment: The question is answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132599/placement-of-images-in-row-using-subfigure

Comment: @rvaneijk: Actually in my case, a group of images may contain more than one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Using some `tabular`s for each layer and the `subcaption` package:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ccc}
     \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
       & \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
     First image & Second image & Third image \\  
     \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b} \\
     Fourth image & Fifth image &
     \end{tabular}
     \subcaption{First layer}
     \end{minipage}\par\bigskip
     \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ccc}
     \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
       & \includegraphics[width=.28\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
     First image & Second image & Third image \\  
     \end{tabular}
     \subcaption{Second layer}
     \end{minipage}
   \caption{a figure with some layers of subfigures each with its own name and each layer with a subcaption}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Above I used a standard `tabular` with three `c` type columns; if the text below the images should span more than one line, you could use `tabularx` from the `tabularx` package and centered `X` columns, as the option below illustrates.
2. Since the OP is using `subfig`, the `subcaption` package cannot be used; here's an approach using the same idea as before, but with `tabularx` and the `subfig` package:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{tabularx}

   \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}
   \subfloat[First layer]{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
     First image & Second image & Third image \\  
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b} \\
     Fourth image & Fifth image &
     \end{tabularx}
     \end{minipage}}\par\medskip
   \subfloat[Second layer]{%
     \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
     First image & Second image & Third image \\  
     \end{tabularx}
     \end{minipage}}
   \caption{a figure with some layers of subfigures each with its own name and each layer with a subcaption}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: It throws an error `Undefined control sequence. \subcaption` because I am already using `\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}`

Comment: @skm You should have mentioned that in the first place! subcaption and subfig are incompatible. In some minutes I'll update my answer using `subfig` instead.

Comment: Actually, I am already using `\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}` and hence I cannot use `\usepackage{subcaption}` in combination to it

Comment: @skm Please see the updated answer under the "Update" section.

Comment: The method works but the name of the group for example "(a) first layer", "(b) Second Layer" are in smaller font than the name of individual images. This seems a little strange. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @skm  If you want normal size for the subcaptions load the `subfig` package like this: `\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize]{subfig}`. The other option is to use something like `\small First image & \small Second image...`  inside the table to reduce the font size for the image names.

Comment: thanks a lot. It is something which I have been looking for a long time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @skm You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Your suggestion worked but actually I have several images in a figure and hence now these images are getting hide behind the bottom of the page. I am facing a similar situation which I faced here `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245689/page-break-between-images-of-a-figure`

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple rows, e.g. look at this example from [ClassicThesis](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis):

```
begin{figure}[bth]
    \myfloatalign
    \subfloat[Asia personas duo.]
    {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{gfx/example_1}} \quad
    \subfloat[Pan ma signo.]
    {\label{fig:example-b}%
     \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{gfx/example_2}} \\
    \subfloat[Methodicamente o uno.]
    {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{gfx/example_3}} \quad
    \subfloat[Titulo debitas.]
    {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{gfx/example_4}}
    \caption[Tu duo titulo debitas latente]{Tu duo titulo debitas
    latente.}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: it is giving me several error among which one is "undefined control sequence. \myfloatalign". Please tell me, which package should be included for that.

Comment: can you provide an screenshot of the figure which will be resulted with the above code.

Comment: I will try to create a working document tomorrow, it is 0h06 now.. ok?

Comment: can one say why the answer was downvoted?