# Use of tabular format to insert images

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats

I have used a table to insert images using the [**suggestion at this SO question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257353/48093). The problem is that I have several images to be placed and hence the images start getting hide behind the bottom of the page as shown [**here**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245689/page-break-between-images-of-a-figure) (one of my previous question).

**PROBLEM:** Though I can use `\ContinuedFloat` as suggested in the comments of that question but then the next part of the image comes in the middle of the next page (if there is only 1-2 rows in the continued part of the table) which looks weird. So, how can I bring the continued part of the table to the top of the next page so that they really look in continuation.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[First layer]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
      First image & Second image & Third image \\  
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b} \\
      Fourth image & Fifth image &
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{minipage}}\par\medskip

    \subfloat[Second layer]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
      First image & Second image & Third image \\  
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b} \\
      Fourth image & Fifth image &
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{minipage}}\par\medskip

        \subfloat[Third layer]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
      First image & Second image & Third image \\  
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b} \\
      Fourth image & Fifth image &
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{minipage}}\par\medskip


    \subfloat[Forth layer]{%
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYY}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\
      First image & Second image & Third image \\  
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{minipage}}
    \caption{a figure with some layers of subfigures each with its own name and each layer with a subcaption}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Providing MWE is not your strongest feature, I assume? ;-)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you're actually asking about [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : Yes, thanks a lot. Answer there did what I required. Thanks.