# Locally put a float on a float only page on top

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28565/45570) it is described how to place floats on a float only page on top with a global setting. However, I'm looking for a local solution which will effect only one float page. The other float pages are just fine with the middle alignment. Any ideas?

Comment: If you know that this 'float' should be fixed on top of the page, why should it float at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings shown are local settings and only read locally so if changed mid document the float page setting will change, so you can use

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
\begin{figure}[p]...
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\endgroup
```

then only that float pages generated by that `\clearpage` will be affected.