# How do I force top alignment with paracol?

Tags: paracol, alignment, includegraphics

I have a simple layout with two columns, and I want the figures in the right column to always start at the top of the page with even spacing. However, this happens:

**Page 1**
[image: Page 1]

**Page 2**

[image: Page 2]

How do I make it so that the images always align with the top line of text in the left column?

Here's the MWE, which should compile with both `xelatex` and `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
\columnratio{0.7}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\lipsum[1-5]

\switchcolumn

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not really related to `paracol` but it's latex's float mechanism. In your example the 3 figures are placed on a float page because of `\clearpage` of `\end{document}`.

Comment: @touhami: Okay ... but can I do anything about it?

Comment: you can see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285156/71471)

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that [h] will only allow 3 floats per page/column, whereas 5 will fit.  I tried playing with \topnumber and \textfracton, but so far no joy.  Anyway, [p] is better.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `totalnumber=3`