# Align float to top of float-only page only at the end of chapters

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, chapters

I think floats on float-only pages in the middle of a chapter should be vertically centered, which is the default.
However, if there is a float-only page at the end of a chapter, I think that the float should be aligned to the top of the page, because if is in the middle, it pretends that the chapter would continue.
[Locally put a float on a float only page on top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285078/locally-put-a-float-on-a-float-only-page-on-top) states a possible workaround, but it would be repeated at the end of every chapter and is not too elegant.

Comment: it's tricky actually. `\chapter` does a `\clearpage` to flush floats and for those you could locally set the float page before doing `\clearpage` but latex might just make a float page on its own and in that case it may do it before seeing the `\chapter` that comes next.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I admit it is a difficult use case.