# Change location of a figure

Tags: floats

I include a .tikz figure in my document using the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}


\begin{document}


\newpage
\null
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{pic/evaluation1}
\caption{Evaluation 1.}
\label{evaluation1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{pic/evaluation2}
\caption{Evaluation 2.}
\label{evaluation 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{pic/evaluation3}
\caption{Evaluation 3.}
\label{evaluation3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want the first two figures to be located on one page and the third figure to be located on the top of the next page. This LaTeX code, however, lets the first figure be on top of the page and the other two figures on the next page.

Comment: Maybe the picture is too big?

Comment: Because there is nothing else on the page, the page becomes a float page, and as such see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page Add some text, or `\null` before the `figure` to see it move to the top of the page.

Comment: Thx Torbjorn! I have tried your comment, and it does work - somehow. But I have added some more information to my question, I didn't know I would need that in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you placed the first two graphs in a single `figure` environment, and that you state `[p]` as the placement specifier. That way, the graphs will be placed together on a page. For the remaining `figure` environment, change the placement specifier from `[h]` to `[t!]` to assure that it'll be placed at the top of the page that follows the page with the first two graphs.

The modified code would thus look like this -- observe that I can't post a meaningful screenshot, as I lack access to the files `evaluation1.tex`, `evaluation2.tex`, and `evaluation3.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] 
\centering

\input{pic/evaluation1}
\caption{Evaluation 1.}
\label{evaluation1}

\vspace{1cm} % choose a suitable amount of vertical whitespace

\input{pic/evaluation2}
\caption{Evaluation 2.}
\label{evaluation2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\input{pic/evaluation3}
\caption{Evaluation 3.}
\label{evaluation3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cleaning up unanswered questions? ;-)

Comment: allright, this works fine, when adding an extra \newpage and \null before the last figure. Thanks!

Comment: @Luk - I had assumed that the first `figure` environment, which contains two graphs, more of less occupies a full page. If that's not the case, then a `\newpage` (better still: `\clearpage`) directive may indeed be needed.