# How to reduce white space before figure in latex?

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am using package `graphicx` to insert figure in my LaTeX document. However, I am getting some extra white space before the figure when the figure is on a new page? How can I reduce white space before figure? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: `\includegraphics` does not insert any space. If you showed a small test document (you can use `example-image` that is available for such tests) that has space then someone could tell you what is making the space.

Comment: figures on float pages are vertically centred, perhaps you are asking about that and want them at the top? if so see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page/28565#28565

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Also, put the image inside a \fbox to see if the image itself has white space.  (set \fboxsep=0pt)