# Table doesn't appear at the top of the page

Tags: tables

[image: This is the problem with the table. It doesn't appear at top of the page.]My table doesn't appear at the top of the page despite using \begin{table}[tp].

```
\begin{table}[t]
\flushleft
\caption{Spectral parameters and comparision with McClintock et al., 
 2009}
    \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular} 





\hline
\textbf{S.}&\textbf{Day} &\textbf{MJD} 
& \textbf{T\textsubscript{in}(Mcl)} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{in}}& 
\textbf{$\gamma$} & \textbf{$\gamma$}&\textbf{Power law 
norm}&\textbf{Power law norm}\\
\textbf{No.}&&&(KeV)&(KeV)&(Mcl)&&(Mcl)&\\
\hline
```

How do I place it at the top of the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without seeing document example with your problem is not possible to say, what you doing wrong. In normal circumstance table with `tbp` placement option should be on the top of the page. SO, please provide a small but complete document (MWE: minimal Working Example) which will show your problem. Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: Is the `table` environment on a page all by itself?

Comment: Please, send us a code, not its image (copy it from your editor and paste into your question).

Comment: Judging from the screenshot you posted, the `table` is on a page all by itself (a case of a "floats-only page"). With most LaTeX document classes I'm familiar with, floats such as `figure` and `table` environments are by default *centered vertically* on floats-only pages. Please see the posting [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556/5001) for information on how to override the default and, instead, place the float(s) at the top of a floats-only page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `table` or `figure` position options `[htbp]`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It will push your `table` or `figure` float to the top of page even if it is alone on page:

[image]

(red lines indicate pae layout, I use figure since your table is unknown)

Comment: The htbp command didn't work. The table is still at the miiddle of the page.

Comment: With my MWE? Sorry, but i don't believe you. It works!. If this solution doesn't works in your document, than you have to me unknown a mess in it. Please, provide MWE, a small complete document  which demonstrate your problem. That it doesn't work is not a helpful information.