# How do I set a fixed position for a figure on a page?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I have n images which are all of the same size. Each of the images is inserted on a new page and the images illustrate a process step by step. I wanted to give all of them the same fixed position on their respective pages, so that it looks like a tiny animation when a user opens the pdf in 'presentation mode', 'fit to page mode' or whatever and navigates through the pages via arrow keys.

Note: I noticed that a figure is centered automatically, if it is the only thing on the page **but** if the caption of the different images cover a different amount of lines, the position is not the same for all images any more. So, I can't do that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page/28565#28565

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm referring to this mode in document viewers where the page is adjusted in its width and height, so that one page fits the entire screen. Then, you can navigate through the pages of the document using the arrow keys.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, this is neither an option because at some pages, I have section titles next to these images. If I'd align all of them to the top, images on pages with section titles would be further below. I don't want to align them to the bottom either because it just looks ugly.

Comment: @Lavair No. The code suggested there will have no effect on pages with section titles (or any text) it just configures float pages.

Comment: You could reserve a part of each page using the flowfram package.  This would not involve floats per se, but as multiple static frames.