# Having white space problem after adding new image

Tags: white-space

I'm trying to add a new image to my document but whenever I add an image and there is no enough space for this image I have a white space in the previous text. my code:

```
Exampel text bla bla bla
\begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{image.JPG}
   \caption{Modellierung der Trajektorien \cite{example}}
   \label{fig: example}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The main idea about the `figure` environment is that it is allowed to “float” in order to avoid pagination problems. With `[H]` you're overriding the mechanism. Don't, use `[htp]`. And no `center` environment, but rather the `\centering` declaration.

Comment: Unrelated: counterintuitively don't use the `center` env to center inside floats. It add vertical space above and below, as does e.g. the `figure` env. Replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`. Personally I would also recommend not having spaces in labels.

Comment: I did what @egreg recommended and it worked but now I have a problem that the image instead of positioning itself in the right place it positions itself in the middle of the next page. What should I do

Comment: that because I did use the [htp]

Comment: `[H]` is an explicit request to get bad white space rather than allow the float to be floated (moved)

Comment: that is the purpose of using a float environment: to allow the figure to move to a place where it fits.

Comment: Never rely on a figure being **right here**. Instead always refer to it by number (hence the `\label` you place. So use `See Figure~\ref{fig: example}`. This way the paper is being used most efficiently.

Comment: @daleif sounds good

Comment: "positioning itself in the right place"  Which place is the right place?  If you mean  just where it is in the source text at any cost, then  [H] is exactly what you want, but if the image is too big, there are no other choice that move the figure to the next page. If you want to avoid the huge spaces, is up to you move the figure code to the next page, where  are enough space or much easier, just remove [H]. Probably the figure is the middle of the next page because the only content in the last page, but this is not a problem, but the solution.

Comment: related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page