# Figure has much spacing to top

Tags: graphics

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, there is a lot of spacing between the start of a new page and the figure. However, this only seems to happen when the figure lands at a new page (I have set my topMargin to 0cm,so that can't be the problem). I have created this figure with Inkscape and the height of the total figure is almost the height of the sphere, so that can't be the reason. Here the contents of my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=0cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\newcommand{\incfig}[1]{
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \import{./figures/}{#1.pdf_tex}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Sphere}
\begin{figure}
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
        \fbox{\incfig{next}}   
        \caption{Sphere}
        % \vspace*{-20pt} I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work
        % it only gets the sphere on the page before if there is some space left 
    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's at least one reason for this spacing: you nest a `center` environment, which adds some vertical spacing, in a `figure` environment, which also adds some vertical spacing. See what you obtain if you replace the `center` environment with the `\centering` directive.

Comment: Given that we do not have your figure we can only speculate. I'd also see of `\fbox{...}` around the image would reveal the actual size (as seen from LaTeX) of the image. And that size can be a lot of white space.

Comment: @Bernard it still remains the same, even when I delete any center commands

Comment: @daleif I added it, as you can see, the margin of the image itself is not the problem.

Comment: You don't show us where the rest of the document is. Can we see the file such that we can compile the entire example ourself?

Comment: @daleif that's literally my hole file, the first page has the section with the title sphere, but there is no more text and the hole page is blank until the next page, which is the image I appended

Comment: figures on float pages are vertically centred by default  ther eis presumably as much space below as above

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page/28565#28565

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the only thing that remains unclear is why my figure doesn't appear on the first page of my document but gets "pressed" to the second page even though my first page only contains the title

Comment: `\section` calls `\@afterheading` which affects the next paragraph.  Try adding `\null\par` or `\hrule height0pt` after \section to create an invisible next paragraph,

Comment: as you have provided no example, we can't easily comment on particular page break choice.  For you example replace  `\fbox{\incfig{next}} ` by `\rule{3cm}{4cm}`  using a rule of a size that shows the problem. Then we can run the test exampe and debug

Comment: @HerkulesOl See this [still  underrated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) about the problem