# Setting @fptop and @fpbot doesn't change default float alignment on a float only page

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, two-column

I am using `figure*` in `twocolumn` document to make listings and tikz diagrams take the space of both columns. I am very new to latex, so maybe there is a reason why I shouldn't do it. Still, I am getting some of my `figure*`s at the separate page (so called float page, and that is ok). The default latex mechanism vertically aligns this `figure*`s to the center of the page and this is the behavior I am trying to change.

I have tried to set new values as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page/28565#28565) suggests but it has changed nothing, my `figure*`s are still centered.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

It is worth mentioning that I am [overriding default rules](https://github.com/zzzorgo/dijkstra-article/blob/master/src/preambule/defaults/spacing.tex) for float placement mechanism and using `geometry` and `float` packages. I am using so called `latexmk (lualatex)` to generate the output pdf-file.

The whole document can be observed [here](https://github.com/zzzorgo/dijkstra-article/blob/master/src/article.tex) (please, follow the imports for complete comprehension).

[image: float at the center of the page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico
I have this line in the above mentioned document, so I believe that I am actually using two-column page layout.
`\documentclass[9pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}`

Or I need to specify it separately for the float only page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot` apply to single-column layouts. For dual-column layouts, the relevant parameters are `\@dblfptop` and `\@dblfpbot`, respectively. The LaTeX kernel provides the following definitions (along with that of `\@dblfpsep`):

```
\newskip\@dblfptop
\newskip\@dblfpsep
\newskip\@dblfpbot
\setlength\@dblfptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfpsep{8\p@ \@plus 2fil}
\setlength\@dblfpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
```

Thus, what your document needs is

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@dblfptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@dblfpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked liked a charm.